# Analysis: Showing a set can be bounded below in the reals

Tags: analysis

How do I go about showing the set $A=\left\{x^2+6x+6 : x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ is bounded below in the reals. Further,how may I go about finding the greatest lower bound for $A$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hint. A describes a quadratic. What kind of shape is that?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. For this quadratic, completing the square will almost do it for you, i.e. writing $$x^2 + 6 x + 6=(x- a)^2 + b .$$ Then you can read off the infimum $b $.